# WordPress get_results order by post date

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using "get_results" in WordPress for the first time and need to order the results by date. What I've got so far is:

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );
```

This works fine in retrieving the posts, although it displays them with the oldest at the top of the list, instead of the most recent.

What's the correct syntax that I should be using in that query to reverse the order?

Thanks.

In case it's more useful, here's the full code:

```
<?php
                // Get years that have posts
                $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

                //  For each year, do the following
                foreach ( $years as $year ) {

                    // Get all posts for the year
                    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );

                    // Display the year as a header
                    echo '<div class="year-header-block">';
                    echo '<button class="btn-year-reveal">View</button>';
                    echo '<h3>' . $year->year . ' Industry News &amp; Comment</h3>';
                    echo '</div>';

                    // Start an unorder list
                    echo '<ul class="no-list yearly-archive-list">';

                    // For each post for that year, do the following
                    foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
                        // Display the title as a hyperlinked list item
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '"><span class="news-title">' . $post->post_title . '</span><span class="news-date">' . get_the_time('F j, Y', $post->ID) . '</span></a></li>';
                    }

                    // End the unordered list
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display posts from a specific year with last added post display first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `ORDER BY xxx ASC` instead of `DESC` to get the oldest first as follows:

```
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY post_date ASC" );
```

Also, if you want to order the other query, it should look like this:

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "' ORDER BY post_date ASC" );
```

Note: by default SQL always orders ascendantly, so you can remove the instruction ASC. But if you want it order older first you replace ASC for DESC.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it in 2 ways.

**From your code.**

Change the below code

```
// Get all posts for the year
$posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM asi_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );
```

to the following code.

```
// Get all posts for the year
$posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM asi_posts WHERE 
post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND 
YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "' ORDER BY post_date DESC" );
```

**Other Solution:**

Create a new function **posts_by_year** in your theme's function.php file.

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);

  return $years;
}
```

and call the below code in your template.

```
<?php foreach(posts_by_year() as $year => $posts) : ?>
  <h2><?php echo $year; ?></h2>

  <ul>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This is really useful, as it will fit well with another aspect of this site, where I need more control over what's displayed. Thanks again.